# Why can't C# method find the name of a Q# Operation using VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, q#

I'm working with [MS Quantum Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quantum.DevKit) using Q# language and VS 2017.

I'm trying to make the simplest quantum algorithm described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-writeaquantumprogram?view=qsharp-preview&tabs=tabid-vs2017) work.

In a method within a C# "driver" (a `.cs` file), I'm typing the name of a quantum `operation` I have defined in a `.qs` file, in order to make use of it. 
VS is then complaining that it can't find it: intellisense doesn't auto-complete and hence I can't reference it.

Both the C# code and the operation are within the same namespace, so the C# code should in theory be able to access the quantum code.

I appreciate this dev kit is still in release stage. But does anyone have a solution for this by any chance?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: **I need to rebuild my solution first**.

Apparently quantum operations defined in `.qs` files are not automatically loaded into VS's intellisense, they need a build first.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a dev on the Quantum Development Kit, thanks for the question!

IntelliSense isn't currently supported by the Quantum Development Kit, unfortunately. You are correct that at the moment, a rebuild is needed in order for Visual Studio to find Q# operation names. We hope to fix that, but in the meantime, we always appreciate bug reports and suggestions for improvements on our [feedback page](https://quantum.uservoice.com/). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for explaining Chris. I’m enjoying it , it’s a great tool and I’m very excited about using it . Keep up the great work :-)